# AJAX loads same posts every time in wordpress loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I needed my pagination for Wordpress to be AJAX-powered. So when a visitor clicks `"older entries"`, the page does not have be reloaded to show older posts.

I've serched and found a solution here. But the problem is, it loads the same post everytime.

Here is my query:

```
<ul class="recipe-list">
    <?php
    $home_rcp = $redux_imd['home_rcp'];
    $rcpquery = new WP_Query(array(
        'cat'=> $home_rcp, 
        'posts_per_page' => 4
    ));
    while ($rcpquery->have_posts()) : $rcpquery->the_post();
        ?>
        <li>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('recipe-thumb'); ?>
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="blur"></div>
                <div class="caption-text">
                    <div class="post-title">
                         <h5><?php the_title() ?></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="recipe-home-meta">
                        <p>Posted on
                            <?php the_time('Y/m/d'); ?> By
                            <?php the_author(); ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
                        SEE THIS RECIPE
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div id="pagination">
        <?php next_posts_link( '&laquo; Older Entries', $rcpquery->max_num_pages) ?>
        <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries &raquo;') ?>
    </div>
</ul>
```

And here is my AJAX-code:

```
$('.recipe-list').on('click', '#pagination a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.recipe-list').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).load(link + ' .recipe-list', function () {
            $(this).fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
});
```

what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`$ redux_imd` in your first line of PHP-code will definately throw an error. And thus you won't receive another page.

Comment: some one edited the code & I don't have `$ redux_imd`. I have `$redux_imd`

Answer (score 0):

As per the wordpress code snippet you added, seems like you are always loading first 4 items it should be next 4 item every time you click on next page till last page.

Get the page number from the url and try some thing like

$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=10'.'&paged='.$paged)

basically you have to add another parameter in your wp_query as

```
paged => $paged;
```

Also instead of using some one's code you can write your own wordpress pagination. If you are not capable of doing so you can use number of plugins available in wordpress to achieve it.

Hope This will help you.